# Visual Studio C++ linker cannot open library file

Tags: c++

I Have been getting this error for 30 minutes now. I have done everything I can to change directory so it can open it up but it just doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I'm new  to this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXVUc.png

Comment: "I have done everything I can to change directory" - what have you **actually** done to change the directory? What are your `/LIBPATH` and `/LIB`values?

Comment: Please provide the linker error message as text, not as image.

Comment: oh boy, that is a nightmare, I had it a few months ago\

Answer (score 0):

You need to appropriatelly set path to the library file (.lib) via Additional Library Directories:

[image]